# Как проверить наличие буквы в определенном слове?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Я написал бота для бесед вк на nodejs.
Я делаю игру виселица.
У меня есть например "X-X-X-X" - тут слово БАТЯ.
Если чел ввел команду и букву А ему показало букву А в том месте ге она стоит. Если ответ не верный то иначе.
Вообщем как можно сделать проверку на наличие буквы и показать её местоположение!?

Comment: А что вы уже пытались сделать? Что именно не получилось и вызывало затруднения? Приведите, пожалуйста, участки кода, в которых у вас возникли затруднения

Comment: Я не знаю как сделать проверку наличия буквы в этом слове. Вот в чем затруднение.

Answer (score 1):

Серьёзно? Прочитайте методы строк [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

```
let letter = 'Я',
    string = 'БАТЯ'

string.indexOf(letter)
```